DOMException Error When Decoding Audio Data from .mov File in React App
I am working on a React application where I need to extract audio from a video file uploaded by the user. The video file is in .mov format, uploaded from iOS or macOS devices. However, I am encountering a DOMException error during the audio decoding process.
this is the image of the error i am getting
Here is my code:
const extractAudioFromVideo = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      console.log("File read successfully. Decoding audio data...");

      audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer).then((decodedAudioData) => {
        console.log("Audio data decoded. Rendering offline audio context...");
        const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(
          decodedAudioData.numberOfChannels,
          decodedAudioData.duration * decodedAudioData.sampleRate,
          decodedAudioData.sampleRate
        );
        const soundSource = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();
        soundSource.buffer = decodedAudioData;
        soundSource.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
        soundSource.start();

        offlineAudioContext.startRendering().then((renderedBuffer) => {
          console.log("Offline audio rendering completed.");
          const wavBlob = audioBufferToWav(renderedBuffer);
          resolve(wavBlob);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.error('Error during offline audio rendering:', err);
          reject(err);
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error decoding audio data:', err); // This is where the DOMException is logged
        reject(err);
      });
    };

    reader.onerror = function (err) {
      console.error('Error reading file:', err);
      reject(err);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
};

What I Have Tried:

Testing with Different Files:

The code works perfectly with .mp4 files, but consistently fails with .mov files.


Checking Audio Codec:

I have verified that the .mov file uses a common audio codec (AAC).




Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78765670

But there is no answer

Have you tried different browsers?  Which one(s) are throwing the error?

I have tried chrome, safari, Firefox.

Do you get a more detailed error message in the console if you remove the catch block?
